# How do i tell google to not crawl a domain completly

Tags: seo, opencart, robots.txt, multistore

I have  a site in opencart  say `abc.com` and  i have  opened  a multi store with it `xyz.com` and i have  found  that  google  has  started  crawling `xyz.com` too which  i  don't  want .
Both the  domains  are pointing to the same directory so i suppose there can only be  one  `robots.txt` file . I am not  very experienced  with  google  webmaster or SEO  so  please tell  me  how  can i  tell  google to  ignore all the urls  starting  with `xyz.com`  .

Comment: Why don’t you 301-redirect `xyz.com` to `abc.com`?

Comment: @unor, that would defeat the purpose of a multistore which is for Opencart to deliver different content for each domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Apache** and **mod_rewrite** you can add a rewrite rule to serve a different robots.txt file for `xyz.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xyz.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots_xyz.txt [L]
```

Then create `robots_xyz.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Hey billy  thanks  for  the  answer but you  got a little  late  .. i figured it  out  myself  but  still  accepting it as it's absolutely  correct